# Clean value of RibbonCombobox

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I get 2 RibbonCombobox, the first *FiltreEtatPays* and the second *FiltreEtatType*, the selected value of the fisrt RibbonCombobox is driving content of the second. So I would like to clean the displayed value of the second RibbonCombobox when the selectedItem of the first RibbonCombobox changed.

I get the following xaml

```
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox x:Name="FiltreEtatPays" Label="Pays" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
    <ribbon:RibbonGallery Name="GallEtatPays" SelectionChanged="GallEtatPays_SelectionChanged">
        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory Name="GalEtatPays" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
</ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox x:Name="FiltreEtatType" Label="Type" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <ribbon:RibbonGallery Name="GallEtatType">
        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory Name="GalEtatType" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
</ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
```

I tried this code but the displayed text not changed

```
FiltreEtatType.Text = "";
GallEtatType.SelectedItem = null;
```

How can I do ?

Comment: in which event you wrote this code?

Comment: What version of .NET Framework? [Ribbon Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh140369.aspx) was added to 4.5

Comment: I wrote this code on event SelectionChanged from ribbon:RibbonGallery of the first RibbonCombobox. And the version of my .NET is 4.